# Why are animal mitochondrial genomes so conserved and small in comparison to those of plants?

Tags: genetics, evolution, genomics, mitochondria

**Background**

[Levings and Brown (1989)](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0092867489908908/1-s2.0-0092867489908908-main.pdf?_tid=75b9e03a-c4df-11e7-a0ae-00000aab0f26&acdnat=1510185149_9f3d2be1b72303ce0e6bc4161482cf64):

> Higher plant mitochondrial genomes are much larger and
>   more complex than those of other organisms. They vary
>   in size from about 200 kb in Brassica species to 2500 kb
>   in watermelon, which is substantially larger and more variable
>   than mammalian (15-18 kb) or fungal (18-78 kb) mitochondrial
>   (mt) DNAs

[Boore (1999)](https://academic.oup.com/nar/article/27/8/1767/2847916):

> Animal mitochondrial DNA is a small, extrachromosomal genome, typically ∼16 kb in size. With few exceptions, all animal mitochondrial genomes contain the same 37 genes: two for rRNAs, 13 for proteins and 22 for tRNAs.

**Question**

Why are animal mitochondrial genomes so conserved and so small in comparison to those of plants?

Comment: Interesting question. Do you have access to [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27814661)? I don't, but the abstract seems promising.

Comment: [Here's](https://bmcbiol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1741-7007-9-61) another.